# Current location is always at Cupertino in XCode 7 iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

This following code is supposed to grab where I live and display it on the map. My current location however is always set to Cupertino California, I get how this is related to apple and xcode is supposed to be related to xcode HQ, however I am more inclined to test this in my current location, it is something to do with the simulator or perhaps my code? I am using no simulator as found in debug

```
  class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate 
{

      @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!
      let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

   override func viewDidLoad() 
 {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true   
 }


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
   {
       let location = locations.last
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1, longitudeDelta: 1))
    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
  }

  func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError)
    {
       print("Errors: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can ask the simulator to use your real location, but you can simulate any location.

In the Debug menu of the simulator chose "Location" at the bottom. You can also do it from Xcode when you app is launched also in the Debug menu chose "Simulate Location".

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode go to Product>Debug>SimulateLocation. There are some presets to choose from. You can also add your own custom GPX file to your project to make it more customizable.